# How to drive luxeon Rebel LED

Tags: led, mosfet, resistors

I was working on a project regarding building a high power LED driver as a excitation light to excite the florescence in the plant tissue. I want to turn the LED on and off at around 200Hz~10KHz.I came up with the following circuit:
[image]

After finish building the circuit, I want to measure the voltage across the LED. First of all, I am not exactly sure if the way I measured is correct. I put the two probes in the anode and cathode of LED separately and use math function in oscilloscope to subtract it and then I got the wave form of voltage across the LED. BTW, I don't have differential probes.

The waveform I expected to get should be when I turn the MOSFET off, the voltage across LED should be 0 and when I turn the MOSFET on, the voltage across LED should be almost like 14V.

However, I end up getting something like this:
I apply the PWM signal to the gate of the MOSFET at 200Hz shown below(yellow wave)

Then the green wave is LED's cathode and the blue wave is LED's anode shown below

After using math function subtract it, I got the pink waveform like this:

[image]

As you can see here, the LED seems does not fully turn off. When the MOSFET is off, there are still some voltage across the LED.

Anyone familiar with why it causes this problem? Anyone has any idea how to solve this problem and to modify the circuit?Do you have any other way to drive and turn the lexuon rebel LED on and off?

I appreciate any help you can give to me!

The LED I use is luxeon Rebel Royal Blue(three of them in series )

The MOSFET I use is STP14NK50ZFP

Answer (score 2):

You should measure the voltage across the 3 ohm resistor rather than across the LED. That will represent the current, and current is pretty much proportional to brightness.

Make sure that your 3\$\Omega\$ resistor is non-inductive (not wirewound) type.

Voltage is only loosely related to brightness in an LED. If you insist on measuring the voltage across the LED, put a 200\$\Omega\$ 1W non-inductive resistor across it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJQ4g8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Plot without R4

[image]

With R4

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am still confused that how to I verify the LED has been fully turned off when the MOSFET is off?

Comment: If the current is close to zero, then the LED is fully turned off.

Comment: The voltage across the resistor is around 0V when the MOSFET is turning off. But can you explain again why measure the voltage across LED does not make sense to say that the LED has been turned off?

Comment: The MOSFET has D-S capacitance and the LED has capacitance (and your probe has a high impedance) so the LED voltage will tend to go somewhere in-between the LED Vf(on) and 0V, then slowly change to a different voltage based on leakages and input impedance (probably close to 0V).

Comment: Please see edit above showing a simulation with and without the resistor. The 10M represents the probe impedance. You can see the LED voltage drops to only about 600mV during the 50usec off period (but the current is close to zero). With the resistor, the small amount of energy in the capacitance is quickly drained off and the LED voltage drops to close to zero very quickly.

Comment: ok. Does that mean I need add a resistor(R4)across the LED? Or your simulation just prove that measure the voltage across LED is not correct and it is actually being turning on and off. I actually measure the voltage across resistor with the same circuit. Please see the edit above. The voltage seems go zero. Just make sure that the LED has been turned off is that right?

Comment: As long as the current goes to zero there will not be light coming from the LED junction, even if there is a bit of residual voltage. LEDs are not ohmic, so a bit of voltage means nothing as far as light goes.

Comment: Is it necessary for me to add R2 in the gate of the MOSFET? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Limits the gate current and slows switching a bit. If you have a driver that can drive large currents it's often a good idea. If your driver is wimpy it's not required. In this case the sim is probably an ideal voltage source so I though the high current might interfere with the simulation.

Comment: ok. It may not necessary for me. Also, since the LED has been modulated by the PWM. It's not always on. What would be the correct way to measure the current through the circuit? Should I use multimeter to measure the voltage across the resistor and use V/R or should I just the pay attention to the voltage across resistor when the LED is on and use V/R to get the current?

Comment: The latter would be best I think, using the scope.